# How to create a new microservice spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I'm using Intellij IDE Ultimate and I create a Project with spring inicializer. The problem is... now I need create more microservices (Spring Boot) but idk how to do this in IDE. I the end I need 3 microservices. Have a terminal command to create a new microservice inside my project? Or a way in the IDE to do this.

Comment: Microservice is one of an architectural design concepts to create enterprise applications. It is not related with Java or Spring so I suggest you do some background study before you start using this concepts. And, if you have time there is a great book on this topic - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033158.do

Comment: Create seperate maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is creating several modules (normally Maven modules), each of them is a SpringBoot application with its own application context and its own configuration, directories structure, etc.

IntelliJ has a concept of Module which matches very well the Maven module concept.

If you go to File, Project Structure, Project Settings, Modules you can see a very nice view of the current modules (in your case it should be only one). You can add or remove modules there. (Also by just clicking File-New Module, but the Project Structure View is more useful).

If you decide going the Maven way, you can also create your structure in disk and its POMs and import maven project in IntelliJ.

In any case, keep in mind that you will like to deploy every microservice as a separate and autonomous deployable unit.